# What is Umpire's Call in a DRS review?

Tags: cricket, officiating, terminology

**This question is particularly about "Umpire's Call". The linked question doesn't provide any information about umpire call.**

When a decision is reviewed in the Decision Review System (DRS) we can sometimes see

> Wickets Hitting: **Umpires Call**

What does **Umpire's Call** actually mean and in which situation this will be given?

Comment: The comments on the accepted answer to the duplicate explicitly mention "umpire's call".

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate.  While the linked question does mention umpire's call, the question is much more specific (to just one kind of review) and is only tangentially related to the specific issue asked about here.  I think it doesn't hurt at all to have this question on the site separately.  It's also a higher quality question in my mind than the duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I think this question easily supercedes or is a superset of the linked question. If anything, the linked question should be marked as the duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 5):

"Umpires Call" is a way of saying the decision made by the on-field should stand.

The rules of the referral system say that there needs to be a clear mistake by the on-field umpire to reverse the decision. "Umpires Call" is a way of saying that there isn't a CLEAR mistake, and therefore the decision should stand.